# pointer on 2d array in a void function

Tags: c

Well, I would like to initiate my 2D array by a void function. But I obtain a Segmentation Fault...

That's my code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>


    void groupeetchoixgen(int*** choixGEN);

    void main(int args, char **argv)
    {
        int** choixGEN;
        int i,j;
        choixGEN=(int**) malloc (sizeof(int*)*2);  
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            choixGEN[i]=(int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*3);
        } 
        groupeetchoixgen(&choixGEN);
    }

        void groupeetchoixgen(int*** choixGEN)
    {
        (*(choixGEN)[1])[0]=1;
    }
```

I Think that the trouble is (*(choixGEN)[1])[0]=1; 
But I don't know why !

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you paste your error message here?

Comment: shouldn't it just be `(*choixGEN)[1][0] = 1;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only allocate memory for two `(int*)` but you try to reference `choixGEN[0],choixGEN[1],choixGEN[2]` which is 3

Answer (score 4):

On this line:

```
    choixGEN=(int**) malloc (sizeof(int*)*2);
```

you are only allocating space for 2 `int*`s, but you access the 3rd element in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In General, `SegFault` in `C` means:

1. You're accessing a location in memory which was not allocated.
2. You're using a dangling pointer to access a memory location

So, most likely, your problem is in this line:

```
choixGEN=(int**) malloc (sizeof(int*)*2);
```

You declared a `int*** choixGEN` but only allocated memory for `(int**)`